# What is an Artifact in Hyperledger?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, artifacts

I see the word everywhere in building a Hyperledger network, but I don't exactly know what it is and the Hyperledger docs don't return a definition when I query them.

Maybe it's a dumb question because the docs don't define it and assume you should know, but I don't and can't find a precise answer to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Artifacts in Hyperledger are channel configuration files which are required for the Hyperledger Fabric network. They are generated at the time of network creation.

These include:

1. Genesis.block: First block of a chain, that initializes a block chain
2. Channel.tx: Channel configuration transaction
3. Org1MSPanchors.tx: Anchor Peer update (Defining a peer from Org1 as an anchor peer)

configtxgen command is used to create the above channel config artifacts.